# jQuery if/else condition doesn't work fine in js.erb files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm running into problem with jQuery if/else condition here. 
I perform a render partial in both the conditions, when I check by placing a debugger both these conditions get executed irrespective of if condition.
And every-time the partial from else condition is updated even though if condition is true.

Comment: Can you share your HTML markup & do a `console.log` of `progress_bar_selector`?

Comment: I don't see the `else` condition that could be rendered in partial.

Comment: you have write to much of confusing code for a little change.Any way i will help you, i will format ur code.

Comment: @majioa You have an else condition there right. I am talking about js else condition.

Comment: @Bharatsoni That'll help.

Comment: @srvikram13 http://dpaste.com/1555951/ does this help. How do I perform a console.log of an element.

Comment: The issue is that in .js.erb all the embedded ruby code is executed irrespective of .js if conditions.

Comment: The *erb's block under *if* condition is evaluated always when `@associated_goal.present?` is `true`. That means that *jQuiry's* `else` condition will always present in that case, and will be executed in client side, along the *jQuiry's* `if` condition block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if @associated_goal.present? %>
    <% goal_status = @associated_goal.completion_percentage(@required_tasks) %>
    var progress_bar_selector = "#cjs_show_goal_progress_bar_<%=@associated_goal.id.to_s%>";
    var progress_from_goals = "#cjs_show_goal_progress_from_goals_<%=@associated_goal.id.to_s%>";
    var goal_progress_display = ".cjs-mentoring-model-goal-progress-<%=@associated_goal.id.to_s%>";

if(progress_bar_selector != "")
      {
       $(progress_bar_selector).html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "mentoring_model/goals/display_goal_progress", locals: { goal: @associated_goal, goal_status: goal_status, connection_and_reports_page: true }) %>");

    var percentage_content = <% content_tag(:span, goal_status.to_s+"%", :class => "pull-right cjs-mentoring-model-goal-progress-#{@associated_goal.id}") %>;
      jQuery(goal_progress_display).replaceWith(percentage_content);
    }
    else
    {
       $(progress_from_goals).html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "mentoring_model/goals/display_goal_progress.html.erb", locals: {goal: @associated_goal, goal_status: goal_status}) %>");
    }
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Bharat, I don't this will solve my problem. It's just a formatted piece of code right.

Comment: yes but here we can check actual problem easily once you have put that code and let me know what happens.

Comment: The same thing, it goes in o both the if and else conditions. And in the end executes only progress from goals from the else condition.

Comment: please console out the  progress_bar_selector values and send here

Comment: I've pasted them in the original question.

Comment: then what it should be go inside if.ok let check with this condition, if(progress_bar_selector == "") let me know is it go to inside if.

Comment: the debugger of js doesn't go inside it, but if you place a ruby debugger then both the partials are called and executed.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final solution which helped me to resolve my issue.

```
  <% if @associated_goal.present? %>
    <% goal_status = @associated_goal.completion_percentage(@required_tasks) %>
    var progress_bar_selector = jQuery("#cjs_show_goal_progress_bar_<%=@associated_goal.id.to_s%>");
    var progress_from_goals = jQuery("#cjs_show_goal_progress_from_goals_<%=@associated_goal.id.to_s%>");
    var goal_progress_display = jQuery(".cjs-mentoring-model-goal-progress-<%=@associated_goal.id.to_s%>");
    if(progress_bar_selector.length > 0){
      progress_bar_selector.replaceWith("<%= j(render :partial => "mentoring_model/goals/display_goal_progress", locals: { goal: @associated_goal, goal_status: goal_status, connection_and_reports_page: true }) %>");
      <% percentage_content = content_tag(:span, goal_status.to_s+"%", :class => "pull-right cjs-mentoring-model-goal-progress-#{@associated_goal.id}") %>
      goal_progress_display.replaceWith("<%= j(percentage_content) %>");
    }
    else{
      progress_from_goals.replaceWith("<%= j(render :partial => "mentoring_model/goals/display_goal_progress.html.erb", locals: {goal: @associated_goal, goal_status: goal_status}) %>")
    }
  <% end %>
```